# PySpark ML feature transform, calls the fit/ transform method twice or overide it?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

We can use various pre-processing classes provided in Spark-ML library.

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer, VectorIndexer,VectorAssembler

labelIndexer = StringIndexer(inputCol = label_name, outputCol="indexedLabel")
string_feature_indexers = [
   StringIndexer(inputCol=x, outputCol="int_{0}".format(x))
   for x in char_col_toUse_names
]
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=[col for col in all_columns], outputCol="features")    
featureIndexer = VectorIndexer(inputCol="features", outputCol="indexedFeatures", maxCategories=100)
rf = RandomForestClassifier(labelCol="indexedLabel", featuresCol="indexedFeatures", numTrees=1)
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[labelIndexer] + string_feature_indexers + [assembler, featureIndexer, rf])

model = pipeline.fit(trainingData)
predictions = model.transform(testData)
```

Now when we call `fit` on pipeline, the fit of all the transforms used above is called too, and similarly for the transform. Am I right assuming this ?

But for all these transformed, we can also call `fit/ transform` functions before adding them to pipeline, [as give here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/ml-classification-regression.html#random-forest-classifier)

Something similar for above code, is given below,

```
labelIndexer = StringIndexer(inputCol = label_name, outputCol="indexedLabel").fit(data)
string_feature_indexers = [
   StringIndexer(inputCol=x, outputCol="int_{0}".format(x)).fit(data)
   for x in char_col_toUse_names
]
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=[col for col in all_columns], outputCol="features")
assembler.transform(data)    
featureIndexer = VectorIndexer(inputCol="features", outputCol="indexedFeatures", maxCategories=100).fit(data)
rf = RandomForestClassifier(labelCol="indexedLabel", featuresCol="indexedFeatures", numTrees=1)
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[labelIndexer] + string_feature_indexers + [assembler, featureIndexer, rf])

model = pipeline.fit(trainingData)
predictions = model.transform(testData)
```

Now my doubts, `pipeline.fit` will anyways call the fit methods of all these transforms, then what do we need to call it before hand?
If the fit gets called at both the places, which one gets the preference?

**Note:** The code above is just created for the discussion/ doubt and does not actually represent a correct executing code.

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing Transformers with Estimators, which are the two possible Pipeline stages.

A Transformer doesn't have a `fit` method, it only has a `transform` method. Similarly, an Estimator doesn't have a `transform` method, but instead it has a `fit` method which produces a Transformer.

In a Pipeline definition you can have Transformers and Estimators as stages. When you call the pipeline `fit` method, it calls the `fit` method only on Estimators to generate Transformers, and the output is a PipelineModel which is a collection of only Transformers.

For example, if your pipeline has the following stages: `[transformerA, estimatorB, transformerC]`, the pipeline `fit(dataset)` call will do the following:

1. `dataset = transformerA.transform(dataset)` // lazy call
2. `transformerB = estimatorB.fit(dataset)` // it will perform execution of previous lazy calls
3. `dataset = transformerB.transform(dataset)` // lazy call, never executed
4. `dataset = transformerC.transform(dataset)` // lazy call, never executed

The transformed `dataset` is not returned because it's used just to generate the Transformers from Estimators. Then, this call will produce a PipelineModel with the following transformers: `[transformerA, transformerB, transformerC]`. You can consider the whole PipelineModel as a single Transformer.

If your Pipeline only contains Transformers, the pipeline `fit` call will only check schema consistencies because these transformations are lazy evaluated.
So for example, if you have something like this:

```
model = EstimatorA.fit(dataset)
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[model])
pipelineModel = pipeline.fit(dataset)
```

The `model` is a Transformer, so when you do `pipeline.fit(dataset)` you will not perform another fit, and in fact the creation of the `pipelineModel` should be extremely fast because you will not perform any computation to the `dataset` (only `fit` from Estimators can trigger executions).

I hope this helps.